# Getting from html form to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to programming. I'm trying to build a program so when a user submits 2 integers into the form, it outputs the sum.

Here's what I got so far

```
<html>
<h1> The Adder </h1>
<form>
  Enter your first number<input type="text" id='a'> <br>
  Enter your second number<input type="text"id='b' <br>
  <input type= "button" onclick='add()' value="Submit"/>
</form>
<script>
function add(){
    var avalue= document.getElementById('a');
    var bvalue= document.getElementById('b');

    alert(avalue+bvalue); 
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use: var avalue= document.getElementById('a').value; AND var bvalue= document.getElementById('b').value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `value` to get the value of the input:

```
var avalue= document.getElementById('a').value;
```

And the value will be a string, so you'll need `parseInt` to convert it to integer:

```
var avalue= parseInt(document.getElementById('a').value);
```